What is the simplest possible way to get a div button to hide its parent div on click in React.js
I have a task that is simple (one line) in plain HTML/CSS/JS, but I can't find a simple and working method in React.
I have a parent div, and it has two children.  The second child is the meaningful content.  The first child is a "hide" button, that, when clicked, hides the parent div (including, of course, both child divs).
function SecondPage({ thisData }) {

    function hidePage(thisID) {
        let thisElement = document.getElementById(thisID)
        thisElement.style.display='none';
    }

    return ( <>
        <div className="page" id="InfoPage1">
            <div className="hidePageButton" onClick={hidePage("InfoPage1")}>
                ✖
            </div>
            <div className="pageContent"> 
                Some text and stuff
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="page" id="InfoPage2">
            <div className="hidePageButton" onClick={hidePage("InfoPage2")}>
                ✖
            </div>
            <div className="pageContent"> 
                Some text and stuff
            </div>
        </div>
    </> );
}
export default SecondPage;

In fact, there is an even easier/simpler way using onClick={hidePage(this)} and function hidePage(el) {el.parentNode.style.display='none' }
But these methods don't work in React.  I've seen some proposed solutions for React that supposedly do what I want, but they are complicated.  They propose defining classes with embedded functions and all kinds of seemingly extra baggage to do this simple task.
I've also read hints that being able to get elements by IDs and getting parents is not in line with React's philosophy.  But I don't care about that.  I don't need the best way according to React gospel, or the most modular, or the safest, or anything like that.
What is the simplest possible way to get a div button to hide its parent div (or make other style changes) on click in React (jsx).

I've edited the question after receiving a few great answers because they couldn't obviously handle something closer to my real case: multiple instances per HTML block.  One of the points of passing the elementID to the hide function is to tell the hide function which div element to hide (in my case, its immediate parent).  I don't see how to support multiple instances per page with the current proposed solutions.

More simple way IMO without using ref, just defining parent style
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  function hidePage() {
    setVisible((prev) => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <div style={{ display: visible ? "block" : "none" }}>
        <button onClick={hidePage}>hide</button>
        <div>Some text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Example

I implemented this second.  It is slightly less clear than Teabag's solution, but it is more minimal in terms of the amount of code to add.  In the end, I chose this approach for my app. Using an inline style really keeps it simple. Thanks for the help.


What is the simplest possible way to get a div button to hide its parent div

For styling; Use a state that will apply a CSS class. Then add any styling (eg: display: none) to the class you're adding.

getElementById should be avoided in React when possible
A ref is overcomplicating things
(You could use inline styling instead of a class, but this keeps your code readable)


Minimal working example:


const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <div className={hide ? 'hide' : ''}>
                <em>I'm the div!</em>
                <button onClick={() => setHide(true)}>
                    Press me to hide the div
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
.hide {
    display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>




If you wish to prevent the content from rendering, you could wrap the div in a conditional render:


const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            {
                (show) && (
                    <div>
                        <em>I'm the div!</em>
                        <button onClick={() => setShow(false)}>
                            Press me to hide the div
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
.hide {
    display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>




After I expanded my question to the multiple instances, I found aspects of this solution extremely useful.  Specifically, I define const [showInfoPage1, setShowInfoPage1] = useState(true); and const [showInfoPage2, setShowInfoPage2] = useState(true); and then an inline function onClick={() => setShowInfoPage1(false)} in combination with the inline style of Arnau's answer.  This is no worse than creating an ID for each section and passing that ID.  This was a great help!

Could be improved by using an array tho.

Really?  In what way?

Well if you have 100 pages, you're not going to add a state for each page. But if you use a single array, where you check the index of the page to see if it's open, you just need 1 state for all inputs.
